# JavaScript(NodeJS) - How to properly kill multiple functions within a module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have many different modules loaded and removed throughout a user session.

Adding and removing like this within my *MainController* module:

```
var currentView = null;
var openView = function($view){
 if(currentView !== null){
    MainWindow.remove(currentView);
    currentView = null;
  }
 currentView = require('/Views/$view').run();
}

MainController.openView('someView');
```

Now within the different modules loading I have multiple different functions. Some of them are repeating functions on an interval.

How to properly kill *all* functions within the module before removing it? Do I have to put a boolean check in every function within the module? Or can I use some kind of global boolean within the module that works on all the functions?

Comment: Are you using `setInterval` function or something more complicated for running repeatable functions?

Comment: Its a combination.

setInterval is used, and Im also using things like httprequest with self calling after x seconds

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` could be removed by using `clearInterval` function, see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval). In other cases boolean check is the best option.